# 'Missing one positional param' error occurs but all params are present

Tags: python, json, python-requests, pytest

The original code works:

```
import requests
from api.signals_add import SignalsAdd

class TestLogin:

    def test_log_in(self):
        url = 'https://api.stg.nuroblock.com/api/admin/auth/login'
        data = {"email": "admin02@thinkmelius.com", "password": "123123"}

        r = requests.post(url, json=data)
        assert 200 == r.status_code

    def test_create_signal(self):
        json_for_create_signal = {
                "signalType": "crypto",
                "currencyFrom": "5c1e4633b140f7000f908897",
                "currencyTo": "5c1e4633b140f7000f908898",
                "currencyPair": "5cbd7faf496a8c001124ed5b",
                "type": "sell",
                "buyTip": {"value": 21313},
                "stopTip": 21312.9999,
                "stopTipPips": "-1",
                "takeProfits": [{"value": 21313.0111, "isAchieved": False, "closeOnReach": False, "pips": "+111"}],
                "status": "active",
                "orderType": "market"
        }

        result = requests.post("https://api.stg.nuroblock.com/api/admin/signals",
                               json=json_for_create_signal,
                               headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ea3d14e631683062073186622d58d2a16HSGB9JDC0ZYtELpwEGL8eNma36EdXei/B72NOa5Y5ln0Sn3+BsWoZdNxK7L2LO4',
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

But, when I've divided it into two classes - API class and Test class, the last param cannot be found

## API class

```
import requests
class SignalsAdd:

    def create_signal(self, signalType, currencyFrom, currencyTo, currencyPair,
                            type, buyTip, stopTip, stopTipPips, takeProfits_value,
                            isAchieved, closeOnReach, pips,
                            status, orderType):

        json_for_create_signal = {
                "signalType": signalType,
                "currencyFrom": currencyFrom,
                "currencyTo": currencyTo,
                "currencyPair": currencyPair,
                "type": type,
                "buyTip": {"value": buyTip},
                "stopTip": stopTip,
                "stopTipPips": stopTipPips,
                "takeProfits": [{"value": takeProfits_value, "isAchieved": isAchieved, "closeOnReach": closeOnReach,
                                 "pips": pips}],
                "status": status,
                "orderType": orderType
        }

        result = requests.post("https://api.stg.nuroblock.com/api/admin/signals",
                               json=json_for_create_signal,
                               headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ea3d14e631683062073186622d58d2a16HSGB9JDC0ZYtELpwEGL8eNma36EdXei/B72NOa5Y5ln0Sn3+BsWoZdNxK7L2LO4',
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

        assert result.status_code == 201
        response_json = result.json()
        print(response_json)
```

## Test class

```
class TestLogin:

    def test_log_in(self):
        url = 'https://api.stg.nuroblock.com/api/admin/auth/login'
        data = {"email": "admin02@thinkmelius.com", "password": "123123"}

        r = requests.post(url, json=data)
        assert 200 == r.status_code

    def test_create_signal(self):

        add_signal = SignalsAdd.create_signal("crypto", "5c1e4633b140f7000f908897", "5c1e4633b140f7000f908898",
                                              "5cbd7faf496a8c001124ed5b", "sell", 21313, 21312.9999, "-1", 21313.0111,
                                              False, False, "+111", "active", "market")
```

I get this error: `TypeError: create_signal() missing 1 required positional argument: 'orderType'`

Comment: I think what you're missing is the self argument. You are calling `SignalsAdd.create_signal` as if it was a class method but it is an instance method so either try `SignalsAdd().create_signal(...)`, i.e., create an instance first then call that instance's create_signal method or change the method to a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)

Answer (score 0):

```
SignalsAdd.create_signal(...
```

`SignalsAdd` is a class, not an instance of that class. When trying to call the method this way, it is treated as a plain function; thus the string `"crypto"` becomes the value for `self` (rather than `signalType`), etc. A simpler example:

```
>>> class x:
...   def func(self, y):
...     print('self:', self, 'y:', y)
...
>>> x.func(2) # wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
>>> x.func(1, 2) # trying to fix it, but not really proper
self: 1 y: 2
>>> x().func(2) # create an x instance, and use its method
self: <__main__.x object at 0x0000027AF1057320> y: 2
```

Alternately, things that should be called without an instance can be decorated with `@classmethod` (the class will be passed as the first parameter, instead of an instance; this lets you still change the behaviour for subclasses):

```
>>> class x:
...   @classmethod
...   def func(cls, y): # we rename the argument for clarity.
...     print('class:', cls, 'y:', y)
...
>>> x.func(2) # It works with either the class...
class: <class '__main__.x'> y: 2
>>>
>>> x().func(2) # or an instance; the instance's class is looked up.
class: <class '__main__.x'> y: 2
```

Or as `@staticmethod` (nothing is passed, and it just puts an ordinary function into the class's namespace):

```
>>> class x:
...   @staticmethod
...   def func(y):
...     print('y:', y)
...
>>> x.func(2) # it also works either way, but there is no extra value
y: 2
>>> x().func(2) # passed automatically, so no way to check the subclass.
y: 2
```

---

However, chances are good that you [did not really want a class in the first place](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). This is not Java; plain functions at the top level work just fine, and are often the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think explicitly passing self might be causing the issue. While calling the function, try to pass the values with variable name and see what you get. Here atleast you will know which values passed on which variable and what is missing.

Like this

```
        add_signal = SignalsAdd.create_signal(signal_type="crypto", currencyfrom="5c1e4633b140f7000f908897", ...)
```